# DragGestureDetector to detect left, right, top and bottom

Tags: android, gesturedetector

```css
// On swipe down -> RIGHT and then DOWN
// On swipe right -> RIGHT and then DOWN
// On swipe left -> LEFT
// On swipe up -> LEFT and then UP
```

```html
public class DragGestureDetector {
    public static String DEBUG_TAG = "DragGestureDetector";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;
    private DragListener mListener;
    private boolean mStarted = false;
    private MotionEvent mOriginalEvent;

    float x1,x2;
    float y1, y2;

    public interface DragListener {
        boolean onDragStart(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                                float distanceY);
        boolean onDragContinue(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                                   float distanceY);
        boolean onDragEnd(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2);

        boolean onTapUp();
    }

    public DragGestureDetector(Context context, DragListener myDragListener){
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context,new MyGestureListener());
        mListener = myDragListener;
    }

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(mStarted) {
                    mListener.onDragEnd(mOriginalEvent, event);
                }
                mStarted = false;
                x2 = event.getX();
                y2 = event.getY();

                if (x1 < x2)
                {
                    System.out.println("sammy_RIGHT");
                }

                if (x1 > x2)
                {
                    System.out.println("sammy_LEFT");
                }


                if (y1 < y2)
                {
                    System.out.println("sammy_DOWN");
                }

                if (y1 > y2)
                {
                    System.out.println("sammy_UP");
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //need to set this, quick tap will not generate drap event, so the
                //originalEvent may be null for case action_up
                //which lead to null pointer
                mOriginalEvent = event;
                x1 = event.getX();
                y1 = event.getY();
                break;
        }
    }

    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                                float distanceY) {
            if(mListener == null) return true;
            if(!mStarted){
                mListener.onDragStart(e1,e2,distanceX,distanceY);
                mStarted = true;
            }
            else{
                mListener.onDragContinue(e1,e2,distanceX,distanceY);
            }
            mOriginalEvent = e1;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

            return mListener.onTapUp();
        }
    }


}
```

I'm implementing DragGestureDetector from this [library](https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack). I want to detect swipe action of UP, LEFT, RIGHT and DOWN properly. My current code detect only left swipe correctly. I'm showing what LOG prints in LOGCAT on swiping.

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link for the answer to the your question.

[Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)